# Warning Icon for cs file in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I started getting a warning Icon for nearly every file I am editing

[image]

Now this seems like a bug, because my code works normally, and the icon goes away if I restart Visual Studio.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause it? What does this icon even mean?
and if by any chance, does anyone knows how to fix it?

For the record, I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the latest release update.

Comment: You (or something) probably deleted, renamed or moved the file or file depending on it (for examle App.xaml.cs often depends on App.xaml) and Visual Studio which has included this file csproj was missing it.

Comment: I wish it was something I had done, but it isn't. Restarting VS solves the issue.

Comment: I also get this. Editing the file seems to trigger the warning icon. Restarting VS or unload/reload proj will "fix" it.
Only started happening a few weeks ago.

Comment: hmmm.. only seems to happen in "sdk" csproj's

Comment: seems like someone posted a feedback to visual studio here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80855/solution-shows-missing-file-icon.html